# How to tap some point on iOS home screen by coordinate with swift/xctest

Tags: ios, swift, xctestcase

I want to tap some point on iOS home screen with coordinate, the point may be on home screen or any one. How to implement it with swift or xctest. I found some solution like this,[E.g.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BaYch.png)

But this must launch target application before executing tap action. How could it tap anywhere point on home screen or any uncertain screen?

Comment: I don't think you can do that? tests have access to your app only

Answer (score 3):

What you're trying to do is not possible in iOS because of the way applications are sandboxed. As a developer you only have access to what's happening inside your sandbox (i.e: your app), so while you can easily do this for your own application, you won't have access to doing this on other system resources.